# Multiple JDK is not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk

**JDK versions (jdk1.7.0_21 and jdk1.7.0_55)**

> Installed and Configured like below.

**jdk1.7.0_21**

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javaws" 1

sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21
```

---

**jdk1.7.0_55**

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javac" 1

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaws" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac 
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55
```

**and i am choosing/changing the default JDK by**

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
update-alternatives --config javaws
```

After this if i run `java -version` while `jdk1.7.0_55` is default, output's like below.

```
root@ssa-lpt:/usr/lib/jvm# java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

but while `jdk1.7.0_21` is default it gives an message like

> java: error while loading shared libraries: **libjli.so**: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

If i issue: **locate libjli.so**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_55/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
```

So it's clear that though i selected `jdk1.7.0_21` but somehow it's still pointing to `jdk1.7.0_55`

Tried to rename the `jdk1.7.0_55` but no luck.

> Not sure how to fix this. Thanks in advance for your help :)

**Solution::** My `jdk1.7.0_21` was broken downloaded a fresh copy form oracle untar it in `/usr/lib/jvm/` that was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is too much reasons why you can see this error.

Could you please run all this commands one by one, and post output here:

1. `file /usr/bin/java`
2. `type /usr/bin/java`
3. `echo $JAVA_HOME`
4. `echo $PATH`
5. `ls -ahl /usr/lib/jvm`

Then - using `update-alternatives` choose jdk1.7.0_55 and run this

```
$ ldd $(which java)
```

using `update-alternatives` choose jdk1.7.0_21 and run this

```
$ ldd $(which java)
```

then again for jdk1.7.0_21 run this

```
$ sudo java -version
```

**UPDATE. Answer**

For everyone who has same problem:

First of all, run sudo `ldconfig`. *It is safe to run `ldconfig` at any time*

After a long discussion we concluded that jdk1.7.0_21 is corrupted.

How we determine it:

1. When choose java `jdk1.7.0_21`, `sudo java -version` give error even if run as **root**.
2. `find /usr/lib/jvm -name "libjli.so"`, this command must show that `libjli` is located in folder where `jdk1.7.0_21` installed. In our case it was not.

In other cases:

Check that jdk belongs to `root:root`

Check that `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink, not executable.

Check `PATH`, java should not be in the PATH, if you are using `update-alternatives`.

Also here is helpful links:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/problem-to-launch-java-at-debian-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16398

https://superuser.com/questions/310371/problem-launch-java-on-debian-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli-so

Comment: Output's too long to post in a singe comment so i am posting one by one :(


root@ssa-lpt:/usr/lib/jvm# file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'

Comment: root@ssa-lpt:/usr/lib/jvm# type /usr/bin/java


/usr/bin/java is /usr/bin/java

Comment: You can post it in `paste.ubuntu.com`. Also add `echo $PATH` output please

Comment: Can you access this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7387652/

Comment: Try run `ldconfig`, then try again run `java -version` using jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7387715/

Comment: Should i try to set JAVA_HOME path ?

Comment: No you shouldn't. Can you also run `find /usr/lib/jvm -name "libjli.so"`. Also did you run `sudo java -version`, or you run everything as root ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14301/discussion-between-c0rp-and-suvasish-sarker)