# java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, java

When I try to run any java program or simply java -version in my ubuntu 14.04 system getting the following error:

```
"java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory"`
```

I have tried the solution in the [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/688400/java-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli-so) link but it doesn't work

Please help me how to make java work in my system

Comment: Please check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/460104/multiple-jdk-is-not-working-properly-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: It would be worth updating your question to include what you have installed (i.e. JDK or JRE), the version you have installed and how you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the server command-line via `locate libjli.so`

Then you need to check executable permission for this file to apply this command.

```
chmod 755 libjli.so # specific path where is your file is located
```

After running your Java program it will be fixed via the upper command.